# PHP print CSS style

Tags: php, css

I want to modify my query results with css styles.

For example my code is

```
<?php
      $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM database")
      or die(mysql_error());   
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $sql )) {

    Print "$row[Number].$row[Email],$row[Username]<br>";

    }
?>
```

And i got a style with times new roman

```
<style type="text/css">
.Stylize {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
</style>
```

How can I assign the `Stylize` CSS class to the `print $row[Number]` output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the simplest way to do so is printing the style into the code easy for printing separated messages not related to the design of the page  :

```
 Print "<span style='font-family:Times New Roman, Times, serif;'> $row[Number].$row[Email],$row[Username]</span>";
```

other way is to add the CSS class name and add the CSS code in a separate  tag  useful if u are printing many things with common style so you can change the  tag once rather than change all the messages 
**css code :**

```
<style type="text/css">
.Stylize {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
</style>
```

**php code :**

```
<?php
      $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM database")
      or die(mysql_error());   
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $sql )) {

    Print "<span class='Stylize'>$row[Number].$row[Email],$row[Username]<span>";

    }
?>
```

very basic yet it's a very useful best practice

Answer (score 1):

```
  Print "<span class=\"Stylize\">$row[Number]</span>.$row[Email],$row[Username]<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap each line in an element with desired class.
It might be more readable to apply the class to the parent, though.

```
<style>
    div.styleize p { font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif; }
</style>    

<div class="styleize"'>
    <?php ... Print "<p>$row[Number].$row[Email],$row[Username]</p>"; ..?>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Print "<p class=\"Stylize\">$row[Number]</p>.$row[Email],$row[Username]<br>";
```

Comment: Using p will cause text to be broken into two lines.